# powerpoint2011 looks blurry on retina display

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, macbook-pro-retina

I'm now using powerpoint2011 on my macbook pro retina'13, and found that the screen looks so blurry.

I tried update my office to newest version(14.4.5), and it has made the screen suitable for retina display. However, only when I start the slide show (by hitting ⌘+⇧+⏎), the screen become blurry again.

Is there anyone who knows the way to fix the problem?

Comment: It wasnt designed with those resolutions in mind